# How to get data by mongodb object id in odata URI?

Tags: mongodb, rest, get, odata

I have mongodb collection schema

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5a9f72ebe0f23d8e609e4f63"),
    "userid" : "1",
    "username" : "XXX"
}
```

I want to know how to query the above collection either through _id or userid which is exposed as rest api using odata ?

Answer (score 0):

Your URI would be something like this: https://yourServer:port/odata/collection(your_id_goes_here)

[Example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1111490/Create-OData-endpoint-for-MongoDB-on-MEAN-stack)

Comment: No I need odata URI query.